# how to make voice count?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

i tried make code, that looks like that (v11 btw)

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', async (oldM, newM) =>{
    let server = client.guilds.get("675326187790270484")
    let VoiceCount = server.voiceStates; // server.voice dnot work too
    let VoiceCountChannel = server.channels.get("722818588288745583");
    VoiceCountChannel.setName(`In Voice: ${VoiceCount}`);
    console.log(VoiceCount);
})
```

I really dont know why - [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxcSx.png)

Comment: Did you try `console.log(server)` or `console.log(memberCount)`? Does it give any output?

Comment: oh, i made memberCount, but i still dont know how to make voice count

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: sorry about that, i will keep in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think better do it with some interval, when bot go ready. Like this

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const bot = new Discord.Client()

bot.on('ready', () => {
    setInterval(() => {
        let guild = bot.guilds.get('ID HERE');
        /* At the first filter all guild channels to type = voice, then map their members count and get summ with reduce */
        let membersInVoice = guild.channels.filter(channel => channel.type === 'voice').map(c => c.members.size).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
        let VoiceCountChannel = guild.channels.get("722818588288745583");
        VoiceCountChannel.setName(`In Voice: ${membersInVoice}`);
        console.log(membersInVoice)
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: but if i make like that
```bot.on('voicestateupdate', ()  => { ...```
that will work?

Comment: yes, but its bad solution. Also you need delete `setInterval(() => {`